# Dynamic Pages in cakephp3

Tags: php, content-management-system, cakephp-3.0

I have been creating a CMS System in cakephp3.
I wanted to create a Dynamic Pages just like a wordpress where we add title,slug and description. I can do that but only thing bothers me is about `routes.php`.

What I have to change to create my custom routes to map with dynamic pages?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share some code? Please take some time and read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you wants your url(s) like

www.yoursite.com/blogs/slug1

www.yoursite.com/blogs/slug2

www.yoursite.com/blogs/slug3

Than here is steps you needs to follow :-

Your routes.php :

```
$routes->connect('/blogs/:slug', ['controller' => 'Blogs', 'action' => 'display'],['pass'=>['slug']]);
```

Now in your view file create links like :

www.yoursite.com/blogs/slug1

www.yoursite.com/blogs/slug2

www.yoursite.com/blogs/slug3

Now when user will click these links you will get the slug value in the display() method of the BlogsController

```
public function display($slug=null){ 
    echo $slug; die;
}
```

Hope it will help you :)